# How to fix PhpExcel extra decimal points bug?

Tags: php, excel, floating-point, phpexcel, precision

I'm using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for a client project I'm working on. There's this bug I've been facing where extra decimal places are added randomly for some cells while reading the excel file. For example, instead of `56.25`, I get `56.24999999999`. I've traced this problem to PHPExcel itself and I've spent a lot of time looking through the documentation but I haven't found anything that can solve this. I can't just round off the numbers to a given decimal point because it happens randomly and different cells have numbers with different decimal points. Please help!!!

EDIT: It is critical that the decimal points remain exactly as they were manually input. So if the client manually inputs 34.25 in one cell and then 51.3456 in a other cell, they should remain exactly like that! So rounding off isn't the ideal solution here.

Comment: These aren't random; decimal float values cannot always be represented exactly on computers that use binary representation.... this is not a PHPExcel problem, or even a PHP problem.... it's a well-documented digital computer problem; and the solutions for formatting are provided by sprint() or number_format()

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MarkBaker . That's quite an eyeopener there. I'm still concerned though because the values are saved as text in excel so I didn't expect them to be converted into floats(I'm guessing that's what is happening here) because if php were still treating them as strings/text I don't think I'd be facing this problem. Is there any behind the scenes type conversion when phpexcel is reading files?

Comment: @MarkBaker Just double checked things and found out that values were not actually saved as text. Making all of them text seems to solve things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment by Mark Baker,

> These aren't random; decimal float values cannot always be represented exactly on 
>   computers that use binary representation.... this is not a PHPExcel problem, or even a PHP problem.... it's a well-documented digital computer problem; and the solutions for formatting are provided by sprint() or number_format() –

I discovered that making sure all numbers are saved as text solves this problem. PHP will read them as strings hence its weird floating point shenanigans won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed this. The quickest solution that worked for me was a small modification in the  `PHPExcel/Calculation.php` file:

Go to `PHPExcel/Calculation.php`

Change `$setPrecision   = (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) ? 14 : 16;` to a low value like

```
$setPrecision   = (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) ? 4 : 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

```
echo round(56.24999999999, 2);
```

Output will be `56.25`

EDIT Try using this custom function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#102641

```
<?php 
function round_up ( $value, $precision ) { 
    $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
    return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; 
} 

echo round_up(56.24999999999, 2);  // 56.25

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have OS x86 PHP_INT_SIZE==4 its true, else you have a OS x64.
16 is too long to OS x64.
In my case, I have a OS x64 so I change PHPExcel/Calculation.php

```
$setPrecision = (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) ? 14 : 16;
```

TO

```
$setPrecision = (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) ? 14 : 14;
```

and work!!!